# pyserial working but it is delayed

Tags: python, gsm, pyserial

I am using pyserial to access a GSM module in my project, but it takes more time to send `AT` command to GSM module and get the output through pyserial. When I do the same task with PuTTY, it is faster.

```
myport=serial.Serial(port=PORT,baudrate=9600,timeout=0.3,xonxoff=False,rtscts=False,
                     bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
```

I also tried to set `timeout` but still it takes time more than PuTTY. Does anyone know how to reduce the time for running AT command and taking output?

Please help me.

```
def check(PORT):

myport=serial.Serial(port=PORT,baudrate=9600,timeout=0.3,xonxoff=False,rtscts=False,
                     bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
time.sleep(0.2)
temp=myport.readall()
myport.write("ate0\r")
time.sleep(0.2)
temp=myport.readall()
myport.write("at\r")
time.sleep(0.2)
data=myport.readall()
myport.close()
return (data.strip())               #if gives "OK" then GSM is working otherwise there will be some error



def send(PORT,num,msg):

try:


    myport=serial.Serial(port=PORT,baudrate=9600,timeout=0.3,xonxoff=False,rtscts=False,
                         bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    temp=myport.readall()

    myport.write("at+cmgf=1\r")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    data=myport.readall()

    if(data.strip()=="OK"):
        temp=myport.readall()
        myport.write("at+cmgs=\""+str(num)+"\"\r")
        time.sleep(0.2)
        data=myport.readall()


        if(data.strip()==">"):
            temp=myport.readall()
            myport.write(str(msg)+"\r")
            time.sleep(0.1)

            myport.write(chr(26))
            time.sleep(0.2)
            data=myport.readall()
            try:
                a=data.split('\r\nOK')
                result="OK"
            except:
                result="ERROR"

    myport.close()
    return result

except:

    myport.close()
    return "GSM is not giving proper response... contact your software provider"
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of your code? - Please see [mcve]. Also could you define 'long time'? Are we talking seconds here?

Comment: @SiHa i have added 2 function to check GSM is working correctly or to send message from GSM module. it is working perfectly but it takes 15 second approx to do so. when i do same stuff like firing AT command trough putty , it can be done in 3-4 second to execute AT command.. ..why python library take so much time to do so is my question

Comment: Could you post the code for your `readall` function?

Comment: @j-p-petersen : it is inbuilt function of python library "pyserial"

Comment: `readall()` seems to be an undocumented function (I can't find anything about it anyway). On my system, it returns after `timeout` seconds. You've got an awful lot of arbitrary `time.sleep()` statements there, and these are usually a *code smell*, and indicate an underlying problem. I would suggest re-writing your code to use `inWaiting()` to wait until there is data to be read, instead of all those sleeps.

Comment: i need to wait after giving AT command to GSM module to let it execute the command."myport.write" is a function that send command to my serial port and time delay is tfor letting execute the command to GSM module